# Inner product space and matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

$f(u,w) = u^tAw$ - $f$ is a linear space

What must be *NOT TRUE* about $A$?

1. $A$ is symmetric
2. $AA^t$ is orthogonal
3. ($A-I$) is symmetric
4. $tr(A-A^t) = 0$

What i though is the $f$ represent a bilinear form, and its symmetric because it represents an inner product space so $f(u,w) = f(w,u)$ therefore, i can conclude that $A$ is symmetric (i think).

Therefore, i conclude that $(1),(4),(3)$ must be true i think.

Therefore i try to prove that $AA^t$ is not true:

Lets look at $AA^t(AA^t)^t = AA^tA^tA =? I$(checking orhogonality of $A$) and i dont know how to prove that its false, if its realy false.

help?

Comment: We could have $A=0$, so nothing (except $2.$) must be not true, i.e., everything except 2. could be true. Or do you mean NEED not be true?

Comment: If $A = 0$ how could $AA^t$ be orthogonal? it must fullfil $AA^tA^tA = I$ isnt it? and for $A = 0$ it doesnt work

Comment: And i mean must be not true for all $A$

Comment: So "must be false". If so, you should edit to make this clear.